# How to put the text in front of a slideshow using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, slider

I've been making a website recently and encountered an issue where the text I want to be behind the slideshow of images is behind it, and I don't know how to bring it up front. Can somebody help me with that please? I put in both HTML and CSS code because I don't know where I have to fix what.

Here's the HTML.

```
<section id="showcase">
                
                <div class="container">
                    <p>WELCOME TO THIS WEBSITE.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="button">
                        <a href="about.html" class="btn">LEARN MORE</a>
                    </div>

                <div id="slider">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="gallery/1.jpg">
                        <img src="gallery/3.jpg">
                        <img src="gallery/4.jpg">
                    </figure>
                    
                </div>
        </section>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#slider figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin:0;
    left: 0;
    animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure img{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    
}

@keyframes slider{
    0%{
        left:0;
    }
    20%{
        left: 0;
    }
    25%{
        left: -100%;
    }
    45%{
        left: -100%
    }
    50%{
        left: -200%;
    }
    70%{
        left: -200%;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, what text do you want to put in front? When I run your code it looks OK, i.e. the welcome and the button are just above the slideshow.

Comment: Hi. I'd like for the text to be on the slideshow like a background, but for some reason, it's behind the images...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text on top of the slideshow several ways. One is to draw the slideshow first, then you know that you have the height of the images there, then set your text in a div which is given absolute positioning - this means it will be positioned not immediately following the slider but in relation to the containing element that itself has a position property.

Obviously you will want to format the text so it shows up well on top of the images, but how to do that best will depend on what your images are like, what size font you want and so on.

Here's a basic snippet using your code and just putting the text into a div which is placed after the snippet.

```css
#slider figure{
    position: relative;
    width: 500%;
    margin:0;
    left: 0;
    animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure img{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    
}

@keyframes slider{
    0%{
        left:0;
    }
    20%{
        left: 0;
    }
    25%{
        left: -100%;
    }
    45%{
        left: -100%
    }
    50%{
        left: -200%;
    }
    70%{
        left: -200%;
    }
}
#showcase {
  position: relative;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="showcase">
                <div id="slider">
                    <figure>
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/300/300">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/300/300">
                        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1001/300/300">
                    </figure>
                    
                </div>
               <div id="text"> 
                <div class="container">
                    <p>WELCOME TO THIS WEBSITE.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="button">
                        <a href="about.html" class="btn">LEARN MORE</a>
                    </div>
</div>
</section>
```